# How to avoid allowing ephemeral port range rule in nftables

Tags: dns, nftables, dynamic-dns

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 OS with dnsjava client library to query DNS servers.

I have nftables rule in this machine which block all traffic on ports except ephemeral port range 32768-61000 which will be used by dnsjava to get results from DNS server.

```
table inet tb {

        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
                tcp dport 32768-61000 accept
                udp dport 32768-61000 accept
                ....
                ....
         }  
        chain forward {
                ....
         }
        chain output {
               .....
        }
}
```

It looks like allowing 32768-61000 range might be security flaw. But completely blocking this port range is adding latency in dns resolution and many failure due to timeout.

Is there way we can avoid this rule allowing port range in nftables?  Is there any nftable feature which we can use to avoid this without impacting dns resolution latency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use stateful firewall rules. Connection state for stateful rules is handled by Netfilter's *conntrack* subsystem and can be used from *nftables*.

The goal is to allow (select) outgoing packets, let them be tracked (automatically) by *conntrack* and allow back as incoming packets, only those that are part of the flow initially created in the outgoing part. *conntrack* works automatically as soon as a rule references it (any `ct` expression). In addition it should work automatically in the initial (host) network namespace as soon as loaded even without rule.

As OP didn't provide the complete ruleset, I'm just replacing rules and don't attempt to create a full ruleset (eg: allowing packets on the `lo` interface is quite common, or maybe the *output* chain could also have a drop policy). Not trying simplifications (eg recent *nftables*/kernel allow a single rule for TCP and UDP).

This becomes:

```
table inet tb {

        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
                ct state established,related accept
                ....
                ....
         }  
        chain forward {
                ....
         }
        chain output {
               .....
               ct state established accept
               udp dport 53 accept
               tcp dport 53 accept
        }
}
```

The ephemeral ports aren't used anymore in the ruleset (there's not even need to specify source port 53). An incoming packet which is a reply to the outgoing packets to port 53 will be automatically accepted. The `related` part also allows related packets, such as ICMP errors when a destination is unreachable, to be also accepted (thus preventing a timeout in this case).

One can now also follow flow states using these command (to be run in the same network namespace as the application in case containers are involved):

For a list:

```
conntrack -L
```

for (quasi-realtime) events:

```
conntrack -E
```

or more specifically with these two commands for example (running in two terminals):

```
conntrack -E -p tcp --dport 53
conntrack -E -p udp --dport 53
```

Of course there's much more about all this. Further documentation:

- [Stateful firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall)
- [Connection Tracking System](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Connection_Tracking_System)
- [Matching connection tracking stateful metainformation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_connection_tracking_stateful_metainformation)

Comment: Adding ct expressin in INPUT chain works without adding ct expression in OUTPUT chain. Is there any reason we need to add same in OUTPUT chain? Ref document also not saying anything about it.

Comment: I can't tell if what I put in the output chain is needed or not. If you gave your complete ruleset (the complete output of `nft list ruleset`) then it would be easier to figure out what is needed to be added or not. Anyway indeed since I'm accepting dport 53 in output and that's supposed to be the only traffic, this would work without the ct state part in output even if there's a default drop policy, except if the DNS server is local (eg: destination 127.0.0.1), since then its reply also in output would not match.